# Multiple if statements under one code, with multiple conditons

Tags: python

French countries names are feminine when they end with the letter E, masculine otherwise. There are 6 exceptions.(belize, cambodge, mexique, mozambique, zaire, zimbabwe) I am to write a program that takes in an input and adds le, or la infront depending on if it masculine or feminine.

Also, if the country names starts with a vowel it needs to print l' infront instead of le, or la.

One more condition. If the input is one of these two plural countries it is to print les infront.(etats-unis, pays-bas)

Here is my current code

```
vowels=("aeiouAEIOU")
word=input("Enter a french country  :")

if word==("belize")or("cambodge")or("mexique")or("mozambique")or("zaire")or("zimbabe"):
    print("le",word)
elif word==("etats-unis")or("pays-bays"):
    print("les",word)
elif word.endswith("e"):
    print("le",word)
else:
    print("la",word)

if word.startswith(vowels):
    print("l'",word)
```

The problem Im having is no matter what input I use it always prints le infront.
For example: Input Canada; Output le Canada.

Why is it not testing the other conditions?

Comment: … and about 3000 other questions.

Comment: As a side note, adding in unnecessary parentheses like `("belize")` makes your code harder to read, and adding them in just so you can remove spaces (like `("belize")or("cambodge")`) even more so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot

```
exceptions = set("belize cambodge mexique mozambique zaire zimbabwe".split())
vowels = set('aeiou')
plurals = set("etats-unis pays-bas".split())

word, sentinel = "", "quit"
while word != sentinel:
  word = input("Enter the name of a country: ")
  if word == sentinel:
    continue
  male = word in exceptions or word[-1].lower() not in vowels
  plurality = word in plurals
  apo = word[0].lower() in vowels

  if apo:
    print("l'%s" %word)
  elif plurality:
    print("les", word)
  else:
    print("le" if male else "la", word)
```

Comment: Does split separate the exception/plural variables?

Comment: @Jake: Yes. `"a b c".split()` returns the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: How might you modify this code so that it becomes a for loop, and you can put in multiple inputs until a sentinel value is entered?

Answer (score 2):

It's because:

```
if word == "A" or "B":
```

isn't the same as

```
if word == "A" or word == "B":
```

The first evaluates (is word == "A") logical_or ("B")

So the first version always evaluations to true. Here's an example:

```
>>> X = "asdf"
>>> if(X):
...     print("hurray")
... 
hurray
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
if word in ["belize", "cambodge", "mexique", "mozambique", "zaire", "zimbabe"]:
    print("le",word)
```

The problem here is that `word==("belize")or("cambodge")or("mexique")` is not doing what you think.  There are lots of explanations of this around, but to get it to work, you either need to do what I have above or something like:

```
if word=="belize" or word=="cambodge" or word=="mexique":  # etc
```

Comment: Should I do that in each area though?

Comment: You should also change the `elif word==("etats-unis")or("pays-bays"):` line, but the rest looks OK.